# Sums of squares of relatively prime natural numbers

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, contest-math, sums-of-squares

Let $x, y, z, t$ be natural pairwise relatively prime numbers such that

$$xy+yz+zt = xt$$

Prove that the sum of squares of two of them is exactly twise the sum of squares of the other two numbers.

I figure that $x^2 + t^2 = 2(y^2 + z^2)$, but I can't prove it.

I've gone through tonnes of algebra only to figure out something else is needed. I could't even find a way to utilize the fact the numbers are relatively prime, as Bezout's lemma makes the algebra even messier.

Comment: Since $y(x+z)=t(x-z)$ and $y$ relatively prime to $t$, then $y\mid x-z$. So, there is $a$, integer, with $x-z=ay$, and then $x+z=at$. We get that $2x=a(t+y)$ and $2z=a(t-y)$. If $a>2$, then $x$ and $z$ wouldn't be relatively prime. If $a=2$, then $x^2+z^2=2(t^2+y^2)$. If $a=1$, then $2(x^2+z^2)=t^2+y^2$.

Comment: Wow! So simple! Thank you. Write that as an answer, please